# The government and the opposition accepted to the Vatican as a mediator

Tags: usage

Which one is correct?

> 1. "The government and the opposition accepted to the Vatican as a mediator"
> 2. "The government and the opposition accepted the Vatican as a mediator"

Answer (score 2):

The second sentence is correct.

The verb "accept" takes a direct object, the thing being accepted.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know if my approval to your answer was recorded.